# Mono book recommendations

Tags: mono, c#, books

Does anyone know if there are any upcoming book releases for Mono/GTK#?  The only book I could find on Amazon with a decent rating is over 6 years old.

Comment: you might get better answers on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) as I feel this is more 'bout programming than Linux.

Comment: You might also want to clarify what you mean by 'mono.'  If you mean the most popular language that runs on mono, C#, then there are many books on Amazon for you--however, I'm not sure how many cover GTK#..

Comment: Mono is an implementation, theres no need for a book on it. It would be like having a book for GCC - We just have a book for C.

Comment: @mathepic: Ermm.  There are plenty of books on GCC (for instance, http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-GCC-Brian-J-Gough/dp/0954161793).

Comment: @Steven and again, thats completely different than a book on C.

Answer (score 4):

There is a page on the Mono site dedicated to [books](http://www.mono-project.com/Books). I hope you will find something useful there.

Answer (score 0):

[Understanding Mono C# Compiler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1469929066)